# Is there a way to Convert double value from database taken through session to String?

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, session

I want to convert a double value to string and display in HTML input tag.
code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="91"> <input
                type="text" value="<%=details.getPhno()%>" class="form-control"
                readonly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You... have... a phone number... stored... **as a double**?

You can't do that.

Doubles give you wrong answers. They aren't precise. Computers are not magic, they have limitations. A double is stored in 64 bits. So, by basic math, there are at most 2^64 unique doubles. There cannot be more than that. 2^64 is a large number, but it's nothing compared to how many numbers exist between minus infinity and positive infinity, which is 2 whole orders of infinity more than 2^64.

The way it works is as follows: There are 2^64 (slightly less than that) 'blessed' numbers. These numbers are storable as double. All other numbers (non-blessed) numbers are **silently** rounded towards the nearest blessed number.

Oversimplifying a little bit, these blessed numbers are not equally distributed. Close to 1.0 (and -1.0), there are lots of em. As you get further away from it (such as, say, a few million), there are far fewer.

This means you shouldn't ever store any IDs ('numbers' where e.g. "add 1" just doesn't make sense. Adding 1 to a phone number isn't something you'd ever do) as a double. You'll randomly get your number changed from 12345679 to 12345678, with absolutely no warning.

It also means that 'render a double to a string' is tricky. because e.g. 0.3 **isn't blessed**, so that's actually stored as 0.29999999999999546. It means when you render a double to a string you must tell java how much precision you're looking for. So, you don't do `Double.toString(...)`, you'd do `String.format("%.2f", theNumber)`, to tell java: I'm not looking for more than a precision of 2 digits after the comma.

So, to recap:

1. Your design is fundamentally broken and cannot be fixed until you update your DB to stop storing that phone number as a double. You should be storing it as a string.
2. For non-phone-number purposes, when rendering doubles to string, the right way is `String.format("%.2f", theNumber)`, where the '2' represents how many digits after the decimal separator you want.

Comment: At first, when I changed my DB to String, it worked. It's half way through the execution of the program. But when I restarted it encountered an error message method to get the Number is not found.

Answer (score 0):

well:

```
Double.toString(details.getPhno())
```

should be enough, but you can also do this:

```
new StringBuilder().append(details.getPhno()).toString()
// or
String.format("%f", details.getPhno())
//or
String.valueOf(details.getPhno())
```